# Mongo authorization failed to database

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a mongo instance in localhost with security enabled. And a user as follows,

```
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "mongouser",
        pwd: "pass",
        roles: [
            { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
            { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
            { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
            { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }
        ]
    });
```

And I'm trying to connect to a database called `testDatabase` using `mgo` as follows

```
mongoConnectionUrl = "mongodb://mongouser:pass@localhost
 if mgoSession == nil {
    var err error
    mgoSession, err = mgo.Dial(mongoConnectionUrl)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

but when running the code mongo log shows following error

```
2017-09-21T12:05:46.496+0530 I ACCESS   [conn1] Unauthorized: not authorized on testDatabase to execute command { find: "metrics", filter: { type: 1 }, skip: 0 }
```

appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to give read/write access to the current db as follows:

```
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "mongouser",
        pwd: "pass",
        roles: [
            { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
            { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
            { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
            { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" },
            "readWrite"
        ]
    });
```

Comment: I tried that too. still no luck. With security disabled it works fine